# how can a language server access a file in the same directory as the source file

Tags: visual-studio-code, language-server-protocol

I am writing a language server for my custom language.
The way a source file is processed is partly influenced by a manifest.json file in the same directory as the source file. In a workspace there might be multiple directories with multiple source files and 1 manifest file per directory.
example

```
DirA
    manifest.json
    sourcefile1.xyz
    sourcefile2.xyz
DirB
    DirB1
        manifest.json
        sf3.xyz
    DirB2
        manifest.json
        sf4.xyz
```

How can I make the `manifest.json` file available to the language server when the user is editing a `.xyz` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the language server receives a TextDocument class which contains a uri.
This uri has the 'file' protocol if it is stored on disk. with `path.dirname(uri)`, you can get the directory of the file.